# Android: set contact photo with ContactsContract insert intent

Tags: android, contacts, photo, contactscontract

I am using ContactsContract to insert a new contact by sending the user to a "New contact" intent. The code I am using is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);

i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
i.putExtra(Insert.NAME, "Some Contact Name");
i.putExtra(Insert.EMAIL, "address@email.com");
i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, "123-456-7890");

startActivity(i);
```

However, I need to also somehow pass in a locally stored photo (in res/drawable) to show up on this "New contact" intent. I was hoping that there would be an easy way to do this, like

```
i.putExtra(Insert.PHOTO, uri_to_photo);
```

but that obviously doesn't work. I found [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/133816827efc8eb9/) detailing how to set the photo for an already-existing contact (via Jak's setPhoto() method), but nothing on how to pass a photo in to show up as the contact icon on the "New contact" intent.

What would be the best way to pass a photo (hopefully as a URI to the photo) in to the "New contact" intent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use ContentProviderOperation's way to insert a new Contact.

```
final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());

        Bitmap bmp = YCardImageLoader.getInstance().getBitmapByCache(mTask.getImageUrl());
        if (bmp != null ) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Photo.PHOTO, bytes)
                    .build());
        }

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, mContact.getName())
                .build());

        ContentProviderResult[] result = SaveToPbkActivity.this.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Then get result uri as the ACTION_EDIT uri, put other extras, startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INSERT_CONTACT).

```
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        uri = result[0].uri;
        editIntent.setDataAndType(uri, Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        editIntent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
        putExtras(editIntent, null);
        startActivityForResult(editIntent, REQUEST_INSERT_CONTACT);
```

because we insert first, we will delete it when resultCode != RESULT_OK

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_INSERT_CONTACT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //SAVE SUCCESS
        } else {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            cr.delete(uri, null, null);
        }
    } }
```

At last sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to add image with contact details using intent

```
 var bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimagename); // your image
    val data = ArrayList<ContentValues>();
    var row = ContentValues();
    row.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
    bit.recycle()
    row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, byteArray);
    data.add(row)
    var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone1);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE, phone2);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```