# Insert Contact (ContactsContract) via Intent with Image (Photo)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-image, contactscontract

There is many Q&A threads, but none of them is providing real answer, or I couldn't find it.

To ensure you, I've searched before asking:

- [Android: set contact photo with ContactsContract insert intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446267/android-set-contact-photo-with-contactscontract-insert-intent) (invalid answer)
- [Insert contact in Android with ContactsContract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459138/insert-contact-in-android-with-contactscontract) (accepted answer does not use Intent)
- [Insert a new contact intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278587/insert-a-new-contact-intent) (does not touch the problem)
- [How to insert photo in call intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215615/how-to-insert-photo-in-call-intent) (is not related)
- [Add a photo to a contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574192/add-photo-to-an-android-contact) (does not use intent)

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574396/492624 (solution from answer I tried with intent, both PHOTO and DATA15 fields, but not working)
- http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/handling-contact-photos-all-api-levels/ (does not use intent)

So is there anyone, who knows how to use Intent (as in example code) and insert a Photo, which is held in Bitmap ?

Example code I do use now to start dialog intent for user to let him insert or cancel and possibly edit fields before saving:

```
// PrivateContactClass c;
// Bitmap photo;
Intent inOrUp = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
inOrUp.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, ModelUtils.formatName(c));
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, getPrimaryPhone());
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE, c.getMobile());
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, c.getMail());
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.JOB_TITLE, c.getFunction());
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES, getSummary());
inOrUp.putExtra(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
startActivity(inOrUp);
```

---

## I have found a solution, thanks to Julien's answer

Not using only intent, as I doubt that we can pass ID of image saved by Data ContentProvider, or pass Bitmap directly within Intent.

Extends from code above

### Use startActivityForResult with constant request code

```
// must be declared in class-context
private static final int CONTACT_SAVE_INTENT_REQUEST = 1;
...
startActivityForResult(inOrUp,CONTACT_SAVE_INTENT_REQUEST);
```

### Add handling result from activity started by Intent

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_INSERT_CONTACT:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            trySetPhoto();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

### Add Method to set photo

```
public boolean setDisplayPhotoByRawContactId(long rawContactId, Bitmap bmp) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
     byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
     Uri pictureUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
             rawContactId), RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(pictureUri, "rw");
         OutputStream os = afd.createOutputStream();
         os.write(byteArray);
         os.close();
         afd.close();
         return true;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return false;
 }
```

### Add Method to search for contacts and add contact photos

```
private void trySetPhoto() {
    // Everything is covered in try-catch, as this method can fail on 
    // low-memory or few NPE
    try {
        // We must have an phone identifier by which we search for
        // format of phone number is not relevant, as ContentProvider will
        // normalize it automatically
        if (c.getMobile() != null) {
            Uri lookup = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(c.getMobile()));
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookup, null, null, null,
                    null);
            // Remember cursor can be null in some cases
            if (c != null) {
                // we can obtain bitmap just once
                Bitmap photo_bitmap = getPhotoBitmap();
                c.moveToFirst();
                // if there are multiple raw contacts, we want to set the photo for all of them
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    setDisplayPhotoByRawContactId(
                            c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID)),
                            photo_bitmap);
                }
                // remember to clean up after using cursor
                c.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Logging procedures
    } catch (Error e) {
        // Logging procedures
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer now doesn't use Intent only to set Contacts photo, so I will wait with granting bounty reward, if anybody has answer using Intent only :-)

Comment: Your solution unfortunately does not work for me. The phone-lookup uri does not return a cursor that has RAW_CONTACT_ID.

Comment: Another issue is that the intent does not return a RESULT_OK after creating the contact. At least on my Nexus 5 I get a "Create contact" screen, but if I press finish to save the contact I am shown the created contact. To get back to my app I have to press the back button witch gives RESULT_CANCELED, the same as if I had aborted the creation process. If I press home or just not return to the app the image-adding process is not happening at all, so this is only a "maybe way" to add a picture, even if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher); // your image

ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
row.put(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, bitmapToByteArray(bit));
data.add(row);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);
```

Comment: This is what i needed. But somehow i don't see the photo being inserted.

Comment: Should be the correct answer, also works for me and seems to be best solution

Comment: This works for me too. More documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#DATA

Answer (score 4):

to help you, i found original documentation:
http://java.llp2.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/docs/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html

and read this:
http://java.llp2.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/docs/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

for me, a simple solution would be if your code works call:

```
startActivityForResult(inOrUp, CODE_INSERT_CONTACT);
```

Then in "onActivityResult" call "setDisplayPhotoByRawContactId.":

```
    /** @return true if picture was changed false otherwise. */
public boolean setDisplayPhotoByRawContactId(long rawContactId, Bitmap bmp) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
     byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
     Uri pictureUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
             rawContactId), RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(pictureUri, "rw");
         OutputStream os = afd.createOutputStream();
         os.write(byteArray);
         os.close();
         afd.close();
         return true;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Normally, this code works from version 14 of the API. I had to do research on this topic.

You can get rawContactId as indicated in the documentation:

```
Uri rawContactUri = RawContacts.URI.buildUpon()
      .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
      .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
      .build();
long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
```

I'm not sure but the documentation will help you. Sorry for my english.

Comment: merge please your answers, I'll try this today, and give you some feedback asap

Comment: for me i have a problem with RawContacts.URI, URI is not found... if you too, we must find another way to retrieve  rawContactUri or rawContactId.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same answer as yeo100, but in Kotlin.

```
//Create Intent - I use ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT but you could use ACTION_INSERT
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT).apply {
   type = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
}

intent.apply {

   //Add name, phone numbers, etc
   putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "John Smith")

   ...

   /*
   Start Adding Contact's Photo
   */

   //Get photo from an imageView into a byteArray
   var imageAsBitmap = (myImageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
   val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
   imageAsBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)
   val imageData = stream.toByteArray()

   //Add image data to an Array of ContentValues
   val data = ArrayList<ContentValues>()
   val row = ContentValues()
   row.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
   row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, imageData)
   data.add(photoRow)

   //Add array to your Intent as data
   putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data)
}

startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not do what the question asked.

Please refer to [@yeo100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430665/yeo100)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803980/2190411) which uses the `ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#DATA) - somewhat obscure and hard to find :/), as contact photos are saved in the Data table under a specific mimetype:

`Data.MIMETYPE` -> `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`

That worked for me, and is much neater and easier to manage.